# Synced folder for the database instead of on the VM

Tags: mysql, vagrant

Quick summary; a few developers at my company want to test some large datasets that cannot fit the VM's disk space. The 40GB disk would be more than enough if it was not for this new project. The way I presumed would be the easiest way to resolve this would be to create a sync folder similar for the webroot but I have run into some setbacks

- incorrect permissions when mounted as root user
- dbuser does not exist before provisioning
- manual fstab didn't work and appears to be unreliable between Mac/Windwos

All the similar results online seem rather hack-ish or requre manual alterations outside of provisioning and I am trying to avoid that. Am I going about this the wrong way or is there any advice on where I should look to accomplish this task?

The end goal is to just not have to increase the size of the VM to accommodate numerous datasets of varying sizes.

Comment: Hi @dasper, your question appears to be more related to server setup/configuration and as such belongs to http://serverfault.com/

Comment: Why not just use a [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com) image? You can box those up and share them that way. Could you use an on-demand image, paid by the hour, that's kicked off automatically and shut down when the job is complete?

Comment: @dovetalk, I did a check on questions asked related to Vagrant and there are under 400 on serverfault and almost 5k on stackoverflow and felt this was more related here. It also seems more developers use Vagrant to provision the dev environments than system and network administrators so there would be more eyes with tangible experience here.